# Who is the author of AggregatedRating in Schema.org definition?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

Who is the `author` of `AggregatedRating` if the ratings are added by me, but they actually come from Google and Apple and maybe some other places?

The documentation does not give any explanation.

So if I added the JSON-LD there, am I the author? It comes from the app store so is the author the app store(s)? Or is the author all the individuals who gave their rating?

Because `author` is actually a required field or at least Google's testing tool gives an error "A value for the author field is required." because I left it empty for now.

JSON-LD:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
        "@type": "UserReview",
        "name": "App store reviews",
        "itemReviewed": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "@id": "https://habinator.com",
            "name": "Habinator App"
        },
        "datePublished": "2019-08-01",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "4.9",
            "ratingCount": "27",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The error in the SDTT

The property name (`author`) in the error line is not indented, i.e., not on the same level as the `AggregateRating` properties like `ratingValue`, `ratingCount` etc.

That is a signal that the error is not about your `AggregateRating`.

You can click the error line to find out which item it belongs to. It will highlight the type of the item in the source code view on the left. In your case, it will highlight the `UserReview`.

So that means that Google requires (if you want to get the rich result) the `UserReview` to have an `author`, not the `AggregateRating`.

#### `UserReview` and `AggregateRating`

That said, your structured data probably doesn’t convey what you want it to convey. A `UserReview` is for *one* review written by *one* user. The `AggregateRating` value for the `reviewRating` property would mean that this user rated the reviewed thing 27 times.

#### `author` of `AggregateRating`

I would say `AggregateRating` items should typically not get the `author` property at all. It’s data extracted from authored content, but not authored content itself, which makes it hard to say whether the author would be the one who extracted the data, or whether it would be a list of all users whose rating is part of the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Individual reviews require an author, who is the person who wrote the reviews. AggregatedRating does not.

Comment: If you take this testing tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ and put an URL  there including AggregatedRating like this: https://habinator.com/reviews/user-testimonial-rating the author is required.

Comment: What unor said in his answer.

Comment: So this means I found a bug in Google's testing tool? :)

Comment: More of a UX issue than a bug.